# Import Blender Files to OpenSCAD

Tags: blender, openscad

I'm just new to this subject so I'll say sorry in advance if this will sound like a stupid question.
Can I design an object in Blender and then import it into OpenSCAD?
I read that it's possible...but I guess it will import it only as one mere object without recognizing all the components? Furthermore, will it generate a C++ code or anything?

Comment: you should read the about page of both applications...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import STL files generated in Blender into OpenSCAD.  It will only be recognized as one object, but you can manipulate different parts in a limited way using intersections and such.  OpenSCAD does not generate C++ code.  After importing the object into OpenSCAD, you can manipulate it, animate it, and export it in various formats.